# Sitecore FXM Placeholders

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a Sitecore solution that is connecting to an external website using FXM.

When I'm trying to add a new placeholder using FXM I receiving next error but in

logs doesn't appear something related to this error. Please see attached picture

[image]

Comment: Is that something related to corresponding placeholder settings? Can you check that in first place?

Comment: Nope is not related to placeholder settings. I think is something related to security but I don't know exactly what. It's working perfectly locally and on the qa server no.

Comment: @sitecoreclimber is your QA server behind some kind of basic authentication?

Comment: @nsgocev nope is not behind basic authentication

Comment: @sitecoreclimber is the  Sitecore.Services.Client.FXM.Enabler.config disabled on your QA ? If yes enable it and try again :)

Comment: Hi @nsgocev yep that was the problem I also find it , I need  to enable Sitecore.Services.Client.FXM.Enabler.config.disabled configuration file by removing the .disabled suffix. 
Details are on https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/federated%20experience%20manager/configuring%20fxm please make your comment an answer

Comment: added :) Glad it worked vlad ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems the `Sitecore.Services.Client.FXM.Enabler.config` was .disabled and it needs to be enable it in order to make FXM work on the instance.

As @sitecore climber mentioned it can be found on the documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/federated%20experience%20manager/configuring%20fxm).